# Как с помощью регулярного выражения найти вторую папку с конца в конкретном формате?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть несколько ссылок:

```
https://domain/dir1/dir2/dir3/ag/lp
https://domain/dir1/dir2/dir2/dir4/en/lp/
https://domain/dir1/dir2/hi_en/lp
https://domain/dir1/dir2/cz/lp/
https://domain/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/lp
```

Нужно получить значение второй папки с конца, если ее название удовлетворяет следующим условиям:
папка имеет название из двух символов (en, cz и т.п.), или папка имеет название из 5 символов - 2 символа, далее нижнее подчеркивание, далее еще 2 символа (hi_en).

Также сами ссылки могут заканчиваться как слешем, так и без него.

Как для этого написать регулярное выражение?

Comment: что-то типа такого `/(\w{2}|\w{2}_\w{2})/[^/]+/?$`

Comment: Ваше выражение не работает - https://regex101.com/r/QLYHUO/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/4Kg40m/1

Comment: @FrontEnder007, первое регулярное выражение будет работать, если поставить соответствующие модификаторы и экранировать слеши - https://regex101.com/r/QLYHUO/2

Comment: `(?<=\/)\w{2}(?:_\w{2})?(?=\/[^\/]+\/?$)` - чего нить такое еще можно попробовать.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(`https://domain/dir1/dir2/dir3/ag/lp
https://domain/dir1/dir2/dir2/dir4/en/lp/
https://domain/dir1/dir2/hi_en/lp
https://domain/dir1/dir2/cz/lp/
https://domain/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/lp`.match(/(?<=\/)\w\w(_\w\w)?(?=\/\w+\/?\r?\n.*$)/g))
```

Тьфу, кажется, вопрос неправильно понял...

```js
console.log(`https://domain/dir1/dir2/dir3/ag/lp
https://domain/dir1/dir2/dir2/dir4/en/lp/
https://domain/dir1/dir2/hi_en/lp
https://domain/dir1/dir2/cz/lp/
https://domain/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/lp`.match(/(?<=\/)\w\w(_\w\w)?(?=\/\w+\/?(\r?\n|$))/g))
```